# How can Powershell on Windows 7 diff two files?

Tags: windows-7, powershell, diff, comparison

Can Powershell on Windows 7 diff two files on the hard drive?

Sometimes a text compare is helpful, but otherwise just telling whether a file is identical to another file is helpful.  thanks.

**Update:**

on UNIX, it is

```
diff file1.dat file2.dat
```

On Powershell, if I create file1.txt, containing the content "hello" and copy this file to file2.txt, and type

```
diff file1.txt file2.txt
```

the result is

```
InputObject                                                 SideIndicator
-----------                                                 -------------
file2.txt                                                   =>
file1.txt                                                   <=
```

if I change the content of file2.txt to "hello world" and diff again, the result of diff'ing is the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit:** Apparently there is a built in alias so this works too:

```
diff $(Get-Content C:\file1.txt) $(Get-Content C:\file2.txt)
```

You can do this:

```
Compare-Object $(Get-Content c:\file1.txt) $(Get-Content c:\file2.txt)
```

This is some sample output:

```
InputObject                             SideIndicator
-----------                             -------------
This is a line in file 2                =>
This is a line in file 1                <=
```

You can also do -excludeDifferent to only show the lines that are the same or -includeEqual to include the lines that are the same.

Comment: please see update above

Comment: Yea, you're right.  You need to use $(Get-Content filename) for it to diff properly.  I'll update.

Comment: For what it's worth, it's a really slow way to do diffs ;) You should at least add a separator parameter like this to speed up the get-content cmdlets: -Separator ([char]0x222)

Comment: `diff (cat C:\file1.txt) (cat C:\file2.txt)` for the lazy.